# Resolve multiple dependencies for the same interface in a constructor using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I am trying to resolve two dependencies on a single interface with two different implementations when creating a new object using Unity. I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with a controller that has a number of dependencies I will recreate a dummy scenario below:

Say we have a controller that looks something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IRepository repository, ISomeInterface someInterface1, ISomeInterface someInterface2, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

I need to be able to resolve ISomeInterface to two different classes and was hoping to do this based on name. Here is what I have so far which doesn't work in Boostrapper.cs:

```
var someInterface1 = new FirstImplementation();
var someInterface2 = new SecondImplementation();
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISomeInterface), someInterface1);
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISomeInterface), "someInterface2", someInterface2);
```

I have also had a look at this post but this didn't seem to solve my problem either: http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/355192 I think this is solving a different problem to mine since I am trying to resolve 2 dependencies automatically in a constructor.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use Named registrations for that; in order to do so, register the types with a name (as you already did to a part in your sample):

```
var someInterface1 = new FirstImplementation();
var someInterface2 = new SecondImplementation();
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISomeInterface), "Impl1", someInterface1);
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ISomeInterface), "Impl2", someInterface2);
```

You can then add a Dependency attribute to the parameter that you use to specify the relevant name:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IRepository repository, 
               [Dependency("Impl1")] ISomeInterface someInterface1, 
               [Dependency("Impl2")] ISomeInterface someInterface2, 
               IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

For more information, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660875%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better to replace these two arguments `ISomeInterface someInterface1, ISomeInterface someInterface2` with the only one which will get necessary implementations.

It could be some interface which inherited from `IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>`. This will allow you to enumerate all needed implementation.

```
public interface ISomeInterfaceEnumerator : IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>
{        
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IRepository repository, ISomeInterfaceEnumerator someInterfaces, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Code
    } 
}
```

Or maybe you can use more simple, but less flexible approach

```
public interface ISomeInterfaceInstances
{
    ISomeInterface someInterface1 { get; }
    ISomeInterface someInterface2 { get; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IRepository repository, ISomeInterfaceInstances someInterfaces, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // Code
    } 
}
```

This is just idea, but implementation could be various